# What's the best way to automatically insert slashes '/' in date fields

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add functionality to input date fields so as when the users enters in digits, slashes "/" get automatically added.

So suppose I have the following html:

```
<input type="text" id="fooDate" />
```

And suppose I have the following javascript:

```
var dateField = document.getElementById("fooDate");
dateField.onkeyup = bar;
```

What should `bar` be?

So far the best google result was:

```
function bar(evt)
{
    var v = this.value;
    if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
        this.value = v + '/';
    } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
        this.value = v + '/';
    }

}
```

Thanks!

also -- I know having slashes being entered as you type sucks. Just roll with it :p

Comment: This seems like a pretty reasonable solution to your problem. What is your actual question ?

Comment: The best way would be to not add slashes when a user is typing ;) For dates you can make 3 small inputs separated with a slash: `[__] / [__] / [____]`

Comment: @gael logic doesn't take into account backspaces. Also doesn't take into account one digit months and days.

Comment: @meze powers that be : p

Comment: @peterJ When your user type a digit, how will you know if he is typing only one digit for the day or if he is about to type a second digit ? There is no way you can predict that except by putting day, month and year into separate inputs, as meze suggested. And that would surely provide a better user experience than slashes popping in a text field out of nowhere. (EDIT: considering your edit, I would suggest you go for something of the like alexl suggested you. (Unless you really want to make it difficult to understand what is going on in the text field that is :p)

Comment: The scary thing about this requirement is that the slashes will be "undeletable", but only in certain situations.  If I type "16", realise I meant "15" and try to delete the last character, I'll delete the magically-inserted slash.  And after it's been deleted, `bar()` will add it right back in again.  A user simply will not be able to change their entry in a "freeform" text input by using the backspace key.  (And yet, this *still* doesn't ensure everything is correct as by inserting an arbitrary character *after* the slash, the magic is completely disabled.)

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from above, I think the requirements as you've stated them are irrevocably horrible from a user's perspective, and I'd encourage you to pursue other options, such as the much more usable separate day/month/year fields that @meze suggested.

Comment: @Andrzej yes once again I know this is a horrible req. haha. FYI -- evt.which will tell you if the backspace was hit. You can program logic around that. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but I think it's better to do a regular expression replace than appending slashes. That way, you will be handling situations like paste or the keyup event not being fired for every single character, as sometimes happens. Please see my suggestion below.

Answer (score 26):

Update/Edit: Obviously the most simple solution today with widespread HTML5 support is to use `<input type="date" name="yourName">`.

For those complaining that it doesn't accommodate backspaces or pasting, I modified the original:

```
//Put our input DOM element into a jQuery Object
var $jqDate = jQuery('input[name="jqueryDate"]');

//Bind keyup/keydown to the input
$jqDate.bind('keyup','keydown', function(e){

  //To accomdate for backspacing, we detect which key was pressed - if backspace, do nothing:
    if(e.which !== 8) { 
        var numChars = $jqDate.val().length;
        if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
            var thisVal = $jqDate.val();
            thisVal += '/';
            $jqDate.val(thisVal);
        }
  }
});
```

`

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCoray/hLkjhsce/

Comment: There are a number of cases this doesn't handle, including pasting, deleting, selection, and rapid typing where the browser doesn't fire `keyup` for every key press.

Comment: Thanks @AdamLeggett. The obvious solution today (this was written almost four years ago) would be to simply use the HTML5 "date" input type, since the vast majority of browsers should be compliant. Just for the sake of nostalgia, I updated the code and added a link to a fiddle to show it working with pasting and backspacing. It should work no matter how fast a person is typing, and I have no idea what you mean by "selection" Adam - we're not testing if a person selected something, we're simply evaluating the value of the input.

Comment: Chris, the "date" input type is still not supported by Firefox, IE (most users haven't migrated to Edge), or desktop Safari as of Feb 2016. Further, Chrome's date input box on the desktop is less pleasant for the user than my proposed solution (https://jsfiddle.net/4msunL6k/) - even though on mobile you absolutely want to use the "date" input. So this issue is still very much alive. I create a "date" input and then replace it with my solution using JS if not supported.

Comment: Your updated fiddle generates double slashes if the user tries to manually type slashes, which many will. I cannot paste "06281979" or "06-28-1979" and have it formatted as "06/28/1979". On firefox, if I type "06281979" very quickly, it will be formatted now, but only because you format on `keydown` which is a duplication of effort. That said, at least it's not misbehaving with select and paste now.

Answer (score 19):

This is one simples way:

```html
Date: <input name=x size=10 maxlength=10  onkeydown="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')">
```

[Here ia a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y6mnpc1j/](https://jsfiddle.net/y6mnpc1j/)

Comment: It's also accepting the 60/65/4555. any other solution?

Comment: pressing two keys at once breaks this.

Comment: Nowadays I convert the input to type="date" and the browser did the rest

Comment: var b=$('#mydate');b.val(b.val().replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/g,"$3-$2-$1"));b.attr("type","date");

Answer (score 5):

Handles backspace, delete, paste, long press.

```js
let $jqDate = $('.date-slashes');

$jqDate.bind('keyup', function(ev) {
  if (ev.which !== 8) {
    let input = $jqDate.val();
    let out = input.replace(/\D/g, '');
    let len = out.length;

    if (len > 1 && len < 4) {
      out = out.substring(0, 2) + '/' + out.substring(2, 3);
    } else if (len >= 4) {
      out = out.substring(0, 2) + '/' + out.substring(2, 4) + '/' + out.substring(4, len);
      out = out.substring(0, 10)
    }
    $jqDate.val(out)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="dob" class="date-slashes" type="tel" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

Comment: Works well when typing for the first time, but not so well when overwriting a value.

Comment: If you have more than one field with the same class .date-slashes it will write the date on those fields too.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// This solution also handle the delete and backspace keys:

jQuery('input[name="dateofbirth"]').bind('keyup',function(event){
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if (key == 8 || key == 46) return false;
    var strokes = $(this).val().length;

    if (strokes === 2 || strokes === 5){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        thisVal += '/';
        $(this).val(thisVal);
    }
    // if someone deletes the first slash and then types a number this handles it
    if (strokes>=3 && strokes<5){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        if (thisVal.charAt(2) !='/'){
             var txt1 = thisVal.slice(0, 2) + "/" + thisVal.slice(2);
             $(this).val(txt1);
        }
    }
    // if someone deletes the second slash and then types a number this handles it
    if (strokes>=6){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        if (thisVal.charAt(5) !='/'){
            var txt2 = thisVal.slice(0, 5) + "/" + thisVal.slice(5);
             $(this).val(txt2);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you should return false for key 229, so android backspace works too ;)

Comment: Shouldn't be '/' is 47 instead of 46 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for pure js version of @Chris's answer

```
var newInput = document.getElementById("theDate");
newInput.addEventListener('keydown', function( e ){
    if(e.which !== 8) {
        var numChars = e.target.value.length;
        if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
            var thisVal = e.target.value;
            thisVal += '/';
            e.target.value = thisVal;
        }
    }
});
```

And HTML section might be(if necessary):

```
<input type="text" name="theDate" id="birthdate" maxlength="10"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time working on the solution that Chris posted above and am accounting for everything except pasting, which isn't a requirement from the original poster as I read it.

```
//Bind keyup/keydown to the input
$('.date').bind('keyup', 'keydown', function(e) {
  //check for numerics
  var thisValue = $(this).val();
  thisValue = thisValue.replace(/[^0-9\//]/g, '');
  //get new value without letters
  $(this).val(thisValue);
  thisValue = $(this).val();
  var numChars = thisValue.length;
  $('#keyCount').html(numChars);
  var thisLen = thisValue.length - 1;
  var thisCharCode = thisValue.charCodeAt(thisLen);
  $('#keyP').html(thisCharCode);
  //To accomdate for backspacing, we detect which key was pressed - if backspace, do nothing:
  if (e.which !== 8) {
    if (numChars === 2) {
      if (thisCharCode == 47) {
        var thisV = '0' + thisValue;
        $(this).val(thisV);
      } else {
        thisValue += '/';
        $(this).val(thisValue);
      }
    }
    if (numChars === 5) {
      if (thisCharCode == 47) {
        var a = thisValue;
        var position = 3;
        var output = [a.slice(0, position), '0', a.slice(position)].join('');
        $(this).val(output);
      } else {
        thisValue += '/';
        $(this).val(thisValue);
      }
    }
    if (numChars > 10) {
      var output2 = thisValue.slice(0, 10);
      $(this).val(output2);
    }
  }
});
$('.date').blur(function() {
  var thisValue = $(this).val();
  var numChars = thisValue.length;
  if (numChars < 10) {
    $(this).addClass('brdErr');
    $('#dateErr1').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).select();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('brdErr');
    $('#dateErr1').hide();
  }
});
```

There is a lot added and a CSS class for an error message for invalid dates.

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/manattweb/meh97ubz/113/)

Answer (score 1):

For react users, who want to perform the manipulation to the date before you sync it to the state, you can do this:

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
   // Format the value and remove slashes, so addItemEvery will work
   let value = text.replace(/\/+/g, "");
   // We substring to add / to only the first part, every two characters
   const firstFourChars = addItemEvery(value.substring(0, 5), "/", 2);
   value = firstFourChars + value.substring(5, value.length);


   ... e.g. update state
}

...

function addItemEvery(str, item, every) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if (!(i % (every + 1))) {
        str = str.substring(0, i) + item + str.substring(i);
     }
  }

  return str.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My regex solution for React:

```
// add auto "/" for date, i.e. MM/YY
  handleExpInput(e) {

    // ignore invalid input
    if (!/^\d{0,2}\/?\d{0,2}$/.test(e.target.value)) {
      return;
    }

    let input = e.target.value;

    if (/^\d{3,}$/.test(input)) {
      input = input.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join('/');
    }

    this.setState({
      expDateShow: input,
    });
  }
```

Comment: How would this change for DD/MM/YYYY ?

Comment: this solution allows invalid dates such as 00/00 and 99/99

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin : http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
It works with jquery.

Comment: As your answer is five years old, I think I should add that formatter.js (http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/) is preferable these days if using a library. If all you have is a date input, the library may be unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. I have captured the blur event though you will have to change the code if you want to use keyup event.
HTML

```
<input type="text" id="fooDate" onblur="bar(this)"/>
```

Javascript

```
function bar(txtBox) {
  if (txtBox == null) {
    return ''
  }

  var re = new RegExp(/(\d{6})(\d{2})?/);

  if (re.test(txtBox.value)) {
    if (txtBox.value.length == 8) {
      txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 4) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(4, 8)
    }
    if (txtBox.value.length == 7) {
      txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 3) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(3, 8)
    }

    if (txtBox.value.length == 6) {
      if (txtBox.value.substring(4, 6) < 20) {
        txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 4) + '/20' + txtBox.value.substring(4, 6);
      } else {
        txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 4) + '/19' + txtBox.value.substring(4, 6);
      }
    }
  }
  return txtBox.value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an updated Jquery version. Just change #txtDate with your field ID

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtDate").keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length == 2){
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }
        });
       });
```

Source: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/auto-slash-in-date-field

Answer (score -2):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function addSlashes(f)
    {
        f.value = f.value.slice(0,2)+"/"+f.value.slice(2,4)+"/"+f.value.slice(4,7);
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Please check the format. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting While doing that, consider improving the answer by adding some explanation.