# Get Date Between Forward Slashes - JSP

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a jsp page that i get date from users. I want textbox to look like this when it's empty.

[image]

And when user enter the date it will skip the /'s and write it between forward slashes.For example users write 03022017 and it's automatically get the date between /'s and make it 03/02/2017.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank for helping and excuse my English.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This process is called **input masking**, perhaps defining it can help you find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `<input name=x size=10 maxlength=10  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')">`

[What's the best way to automatically insert slashes '/' in date fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005877/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-insert-slashes-in-date-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). Though this sample doesn't keep slash (/) by default, it will create after two digits entered.

Your Date field looks,

```
<input id="txtDate" type="text" maxlength="10"/>
```

And your respective script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#startDate").keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode != 8){    
            if ($(this).val().length == 2){
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }
        }
    });   
});
```

Hope this helps. See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjdp03xu/2/).