# auto slash in date field to remain permanent using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, field

I can add auto slash to the date field.But when I hit backspace, I need the backslash to remain where it is.

```
var keycode = event.which,
    value = $(current).val(),
    position1 = 3,
    position2 = 6;
if((value.length === (position1 - 1)) || 
   (value.length === (position2 - 1))){
    if (keycode === 8) {
       value = value + '/';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother? Just let the user type the date. How do you deal wither cursor keys? Pasted text? Text entered out of sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4msunL6k/) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005877/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-insert-slashes-in-date-fields)

```
var format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
var match = new RegExp(format
    .replace(/(\w+)\W(\w+)\W(\w+)/, "^\\s*($1)\\W*($2)?\\W*($3)?([0-9]*).*")
    .replace(/m|d|y/g, "\\d"));
var replace = "$1/$2/$3$4"
    .replace(/\//g, format.match(/\W/));

function doFormat(target)
{
    target.value = target.value
        .replace(/(^|\W)(?=\d\W)/g, "$10")   // padding
        .replace(match, replace)             // fields
        .replace(/(\W)+/g, "$1");            // remove repeats
}

$("input[name='birthdate']:first").keyup(function(e) {
   if(!e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode > 46))
      doFormat(e.target)
});
```

Update

Try this one [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCoray/hLkjhsce/) that uses HTML5

Comment: Thanks, but I can still remove the backslash. I want that slash to be a permanent one. When I use backspace, the slash shouldn't disappear.

Comment: note that this also allows for invalid dates such as 00/00/0000 and 99/99/9999