# Issue with auto population of slashes in date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, autocomplete, slash

I am using following javascript code to autopopulate slashes and colons in a date field

**Javascript**

```
var $dateField = jQuery('input[name='dateFieldId']');
//Bind keyup/keydown to the input
$dateField.bind('keyup', 'keydown', function (e) {
    // if backspace, do nothing:
    var thisVal;
    var appender = '';
    if (e.which !== 8) {
        var numChars = $dateField.val().length;
        // insert '/' after 2nd and 5th character is entered
        if (numChars === 2 || numChars === 5) {
            appender = '/';
        }
        // insert whitespace after 10th character is entered
        else if (numChars === 10) {
            appender = ' ';
        }
        // insert ':' after 13th character is entered
        else if (numChars === 13) {
             appender = ':';
        }
    }
    thisVal = $dateField.val() + appender;
    $dateField.val(thisVal);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form:input size="26" type="text" class="form-control" name="dateFieldId" id="dateFieldId" path="dateFieldId" value="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" maxlength="16" />
```

This is working fine on latest browsers on desktops. But its failing in old version of chrome browsers and chrome/firefox on android. One issue is that when key is pressed in datefield the focus is lost sometimes. Another is that along with the slash it adds the existing value again

For example when I type '28', instead of having '28/' which is my expected it adds 28 again after filling the slash which results in '28/280' as shown below

[image]

If anyone have encountered this please let me know. I was referring following post to do this
[What's the best way to automatically insert slashes '/' in date fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005877/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-insert-slashes-in-date-fields)

Comment: Post the input code too.

Comment: Just don't do it, leave data entry up to users. You will end up with a dysfunctional UI that is a total pain to use.

Comment: @Gustonez, have added the html too.

Comment: @RobG, Unfortunately that's a customer requirement :(

Comment: @Nevin—sometimes customers ask for things that aren't sensible. :-(