# Form Input not allowing me to delete added "/" for CC expiration field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am attempting to create a text box that accepts an expiration date from a CC.  When the user types, I want to add a slash (/) after the first two numbers (to format the text like MM/YY).  This works just fine.  However, when I attempt to delete numbers after the slash has been added, my code just keeps adding the slash back in and won't let me delete any further.  I referenced this article ([Detect backspace and del on "input" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906885/detect-backspace-and-del-on-input-event)) on how to detect backspace or delete on input event and built it into my code, but still doesn't work.  Any thoughts on how I can get this to work or where I am going wrong?

```
//textbox
<div><label for="expiryBx">Expiration Date</label><div><input type="text" id="expiryBx" name="expiryBx" maxlength="5" placeholder="MM/YY"></div></div>

//add "/" (slash) after two chars to make it look like an expiration date
$('#expiryBx').on('keyup',function(e){
  //var KeyPress = e.which;
  var KeyPress = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  console.log('poll number of keys pressed ' + this.value.length);
  console.log('poll keypressed ' + KeyPress);

//add the slash
  if(this.value.length === 2 && (KeyPress !== 8 || KeyPress !== 46)){

    this.value = this.value + '/';

  }

//after 5 chars (4 + slash) split the string so that I can use it elsewhere
  if(this.value.length === 5){

    var FullExpiry = this.value;
    expiryValues = FullExpiry.split('/');
    var ExpMnt = expiryValues[0]; 
    var ExpYr = expiryValues[1]; 
    var ExpFinalYMnt = 'string:' + ExpMnt;
    var ExpFinalYr = '20' + ExpYr;
    console.log('poll ' + ExpMnt);
    console.log('poll ' + ExpYr);
    
  }


});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this the behaviour ur expecting

```js
//add "/" (slash) after two chars to make it look like an expiration date
$('#expiryBx').on('keyup',function(e){
  //var KeyPress = e.which;
  var KeyPress = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  console.log('poll number of keys pressed ' + this.value.length);
  console.log('poll keypressed ' + KeyPress);

//add the slash && (KeyPress !== 8 || KeyPress !== 46)
  if(this.value.length === 2 && KeyPress !== 8 && KeyPress !== 46 ){

    this.value = this.value + '/';

  }

//after 5 chars (4 + slash) split the string so that I can use it elsewhere
  if(this.value.length === 5){

    var FullExpiry = this.value;
    expiryValues = FullExpiry.split('/');
    var ExpMnt = expiryValues[0]; 
    var ExpYr = expiryValues[1]; 
    var ExpFinalYMnt = 'string:' + ExpMnt;
    var ExpFinalYr = '20' + ExpYr;
    console.log('poll ' + ExpMnt);
    console.log('poll ' + ExpYr);
    
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//textbox
<div><label for="expiryBx">Expiration Date</label><div><input type="text" id="expiryBx" name="expiryBx" maxlength="5" placeholder="MM/YY"></div></div>
```

Comment: That did it.  Is this all you changed?  if(this.value.length === 2 && KeyPress !== 8 && KeyPress !== 46 )

Comment: yep. but u need to add more validations. refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005877/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-insert-slashes-in-date-fields)